# Unrecognized import path "main/testPackage" when running Go image

Tags: go, docker, import, get

I am attempting to compile a golang project using docker, I am having trouble getting "go get" to compile the packages for me. the entire setup of the container can be seen below in my dockerfile:

```sh
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm

# gcc for cgo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        make \
        pkg-config \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.8
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL https://golang.org/dl/go$GOLANG_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 53ab94104ee3923e228a2cb2116e5e462ad3ebaeea06ff04463479d7f12d27ca

RUN curl -fsSL "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL" -o golang.tar.gz \
    && echo "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_SHA256  golang.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -C /usr/local -xzf golang.tar.gz \
    && rm golang.tar.gz

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
ENV CGO_ENABLED 0
ENV GOOS linux

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"

WORKDIR $GOPATH

RUN go get github.com/lib/pq

ENTRYPOINT ["go", "get", "."]
```

I build this container then use it to compile my go code using this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v /path/to/my/project:/usr/src/main -w /usr/src/main go:compiler
```

this finds the main.go in my project folder, reads through it.. but gives me this error when it encounters my import statements:

> unrecognized import path "main/testPackage" (import path does not
>   begin with hostname)

from what I have found in documentation, my understanding is the import path should be the folder in src, i.e. "main" in my case, followed by the directory structure.. what am I doing wrong? am I using go get incorrectly?

Comment: I fixed it by using: import "./testPackage", rather than: import "main/testPackage"

Comment: maybe not though, the relative path is not ideal

Comment: no, don't use relative imports, figure out why your directory structure is broken. Your run command seems to put the code in `/usr/src/main`, and build from there, but that's not in your GOPATH.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out by making changing the volume to 

"-v  /path/to/my/file:/go/src/main" 

which is the gopath of the directory.. i was confused because most of that structure came from the main golang docker image, so i didnt understand why they would have a setup that didnt use the gopath.. anyway, all is well and working now. thanks